# matplotlib graph plotting

Tags: jupyter

I wish to plot a 2D scatter plot with values in the range [-0.5, 0.5] and [-0.5,0.5] for x and y coordinates respectively

```
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=[7,7])
axes1 = fig1.add_axes([1,1,1,1])
axes1.set_xlabel("xlabel")
axes1.set_ylabel("ylabel")
axes1.set_title("Emotions Quadrants")
axes1.spines['left'].set_position(('axes', 0.5))
axes1.spines['bottom'].set_position(('axes', 0.5))
axes1.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, label="test")
```

above code scales and x and y coordinates according to to the data. I wish to show x and y coordinates from -0.5 to 0.5 equally spaced for both the axes and then plot the scatter graph

[I wish to keep the axes intersecting at 0,0 and not scale according to the data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyXaN.png)

---

Edit
by taking x and y values as
xvals = [0.237, 0.415, -0.264, 0.142, -0.037, -0.088, -0.143, -0.332, 0.166, -0.079]
y vals= [0.265, 0.325, -0.069, 0.086, -0.136, 0.124, -0.051, -0.052, 0.280, 0.121]

I am getting following plot with @r-beginners answer
[enter image description here][2]

I want the origin to be in the center and points not scaled and not shift downward
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxGIs.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the axis to the desired range and the frame to the center, you will get the graph you want.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#x_vals = np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,10)
#y_vals = np.linspace(-0.5,0.5,10)

x_vals = [0.237, 0.415, -0.264, 0.142, -0.037, -0.088, -0.143, -0.332, 0.166, -0.079]
y_vals= [0.265, 0.325, -0.069, 0.086, -0.136, 0.124, -0.051, -0.052, 0.280, 0.121]

x_vals_center = (np.max(x_vals) + np.min(x_vals)) / 2
y_vals_center = (np.max(y_vals) + np.min(y_vals)) / 2

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=[7,7])
axes1 = fig1.add_axes([-0.5,-0.5,0.5,0.5])
axes1.set_xlabel("xlabel", labelpad=0)
axes1.set_ylabel("ylabel", labelpad=110)
axes1.set_title("Emotions Quadrants")
axes1.spines[['top', 'right']].set_visible(False)
#axes1.spines[['left','bottom']].set_position(('data', 0))

axes1.spines['left'].set_position(('data', x_vals_center))
axes1.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data', y_vals_center))

axes1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
axes1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

axes1.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, label="test")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Sorry but your method works only if the points are uniformly distrubuted along the y axis. there are more points in 3rd qudrant then it will not work

Comment: try with xvals = [0.237, 0.415, -0.264, 0.142, -0.037, -0.088, -0.143, -0.332, 0.166, -0.079]

y vals= [0.265, 0.325, -0.069, 0.086, -0.136, 0.124, -0.051, -0.052, 0.280, 0.121]

Comment: I understood what you pointed out. I changed it so that it always intersects at zero, without affecting the values I draw.

Comment: Yes. It is almost correct. But I wanted the axes to be at the center of the image. Please see @Scott Boston answer. Thanks for your help though

Comment: The setting of `set_position(('axes', 0.5))` only sets the axis to half of 1.0, so if the length of the axis changes it will not be the center you want.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts. However, i wanted all the 4 quadrants of the equal area for visualization purpose. The accepted answer shows the graph as i wanted

Comment: What I meant to say is that the 0.5 setting may or may not work for all data. I have changed the code to make the area of the four events the same for any data. In this example, the areas are the same but the zero points do not match.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

```
x_vals = [0.237, 0.415, -0.264, 0.142, -0.037, -0.088, -0.143, -0.332, 0.166, -0.079] 
y_vals= [0.265, 0.325, -0.069, 0.086, -0.136, 0.124, -0.051, -0.052, 0.280, 0.121] 

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=[7,7])
axes1 = fig1.add_axes([-0.5,-0.5,0.5,0.5])
axes1.set_xlabel("xlabel", labelpad=110)
axes1.set_ylabel("ylabel", labelpad=110)
axes1.set_title("Emotions Quadrants")
axes1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
axes1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

axes1.spines['left'].set_position(('axes', 0.5))
axes1.spines['bottom'].set_position(('axes', 0.5))

axes1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
axes1.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

axes1.scatter(x_vals, y_vals, label="test")
axes1.set_ylabel('Arousal')
axes1.set_xlabel('Valence')

axes1.set_ylim(-.5,.5)
axes1.set_xlim(-.5,.5)

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]